# Linux Bash Shell Script -p not a valid identifier

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am creating a program that should compare the user input with strings from a file.

Input: `./script Questions.txt Answers.txt`

Here is my program:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a existing_answ
i=0
j=0
Number_of_correct_answers=0
Number_of_wrong_answers=0
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    existing_answ[$i]="$line"
    let "i=i+1"
done < "$2"

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    echo "$line"
    while [ -z "$arg1" ]
    do
            read –p "Your answer: " arg1
    done


    if [[ ${existing_answ[$j]} == "$arg1" ]]
    then
            let "Number_of_correct_answers++"
    else
            let "Number_of_wrong_answers++"
    fi
    let "j=j+1"
done < "$1"
echo "$Number_of_correct_answers"
echo "$Number_of_wrong_answers"
```

What a get is an infinite loop saying that `-p is not a valid identifier`
The same script for user input worked at my previous programs, here it doesn't.
Did I miss something or what's wrong with it?

Comment: Given "compare user input with a file", why not just do `if grep "$2" $1 ; then echo Found it ; else echo "not there" ; fi` Good luck

Comment: Sounds like you are running it with `sh` instead of `bash`.

Comment: `read –p` the character before `p` is not a simple dash. Erase that line and re-type it (and never use a fancy word processor or copy/paste stuff from the webs). It's an ENDASH \u2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that instead of an ASCII hyphen-minus character in `-p`, the character before the `p` is a [typographic en-dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). You should replace this with a regular ASCII hyphen-minus.